# display radio button value from sql on page load

Tags: php, sql, forms, radio-button

Making a form to edit sql table, form uses radio button and so user can see the existing value, when page loads, I would like my radio buttons to be indicated on/off according to the db. There are 2 buttons, they send values 0 & 1. I'm currently using isset with no success. Is there a better (correct) way to do this? My php is working for the text fields, but with the radio nothing is selected.

```
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="transaction" value="0" <?php if (isset($transaction) && $transaction === '0' ) { echo 'checked="checked"';}?>/>
              Listings</label>
            <br />
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="transaction" value="1" <?php if (isset($transaction) && $transaction === '1' ) { echo 'checked="checked"';}?>/>
              Transaction History</label>
```

Comment: Since you're using `===` are you sure the value of `$transaction` is a string?

Comment: so should be identical to 0 or 1 using ===. @alliterativeAlice, I'm embarrassed I'm not following you here

Comment: `===` checks the type of the variable, not just its value, try using just `==`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the value of `$transaction` is a number, not a string. Change the comparison to check against a number, not against a string:

```
<input type="radio" name="transaction" value="0" <?php if (isset($transaction) && $transaction === 0 ) { echo 'checked';}?>/>
<input type="radio" name="transaction" value="1" <?php if (isset($transaction) && $transaction === 1 ) { echo 'checked';}?>/>
```

Alternatively, use the weak equality `==` operator to just compare the values, not the types:

```
<input type="radio" name="transaction" value="0" <?php if (isset($transaction) && $transaction == '0' ) { echo 'checked';}?>/>
<input type="radio" name="transaction" value="1" <?php if (isset($transaction) && $transaction == '1' ) { echo 'checked';}?>/>
```